# What is the last digit of $12^{12^{12^{12}}}$?

Tags: number-theory

What is the last digit of $12^{12^{12^{12}}}$? I know that the last digit of $12^k$ repeats the pattern $2,4,8,6,\cdots$. I know the answer is $6$, so I suppose that we must have $12^{12^{12}}=4n$ So the question is reduced to solve

$$12^{12^{12}}\equiv x (\mod 4)$$

But I'm not sure how to solve that equation since $4$ is not a prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. $12^n \equiv 0 \mod 4$, as $4$ divides $12$.

Answer (score 2):

$12$ is a multiple of $4$, so certainly $12^{12^{12}}$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Oh yeah of course! Thanks! I was searching for possible variations on format's little theorem -_-" haha